# Second order Poisson ODE

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method, wolfram-physics

I have a 2nd differential Poisson equation for the electric field in a semiconductor (application for a MOS simulation, hopefully).
I have the formula:
[image: Poisson Equation]

with the condition that after a certain value(let's say 1.5*xp), the value becomes constant and the derivate tends to 0.

[image]

The results of NDSolve is just the scalar Ev0 instead of a function depending on x.
[image]

I am not an expert in Mathematica so I would love help and especially a simple enough explanation on how to resolve this with this problem (so I can use the knowledge for other programs too).

Thank you.

The code I tried:

```
NA = 1.45*10^16*10^6; q = 1.602/10^19; T = 300; k = 1.38/10^23; kb = k/q; xp = 2.60383/10^7; EgT = 1.123; \[Epsilon]s = 1.03592/10^10; Ev0 = -0.167533; NC300 = 2.78*10^25; NV300 = 9.48*10^24; 
sol = NDSolve[{Derivative[2][Ev][x] - (q^2/\[Epsilon]s)*(-NA - NC300/E^((EgT + Ev[x])/(kb*T)) + NV300*E^(Ev[x]/(kb*T))) == 0 + NeumannValue[0, x >= 1.5*xp], 
DirichletCondition[{Ev[x] == Ev0}, x >= 1.5*xp]}, Ev[x], {x, 0, 3*xp}]
Plot[{Evaluate[Ev[x] /. sol], Ev0}, {x, 0, 5*xp}]
```

Comment: Please directly post the Mathematica code.

Comment: `NDSolve[{Derivative[2][Ev][x] - (q^2/\[Epsilon]s)*(-NA - NC300/E^((Eg[T] + Ev[x])/(kb*T)) + NV300*E^(Ev[x]/(kb*T))) == 0 + NeumannValue[0, x >= 1.5*xp], 
DirichletCondition[{Ev[x] == Ev0}, x >= 1.5*xp]}, Ev[x], {x, 0, 3*xp}]`

Comment: Please update the post. Make sure that the complete code is given. It is very boring for us to try to type the code you have from an image when you already have a typed version. Make it easy for us to help you.

Comment: Added in the end of the post, the code and the values of the parameters used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some sort of a scaling problem:

```
NA = 1; q = 1; T = 3; k = 1; kb = k/q; xp = 1;
EgT = 1; \[Epsilon]s = 1; Ev0 = -1; NC300 = 2; NV300 = 9;
sol = NDSolveValue[{Derivative[2][Ev][
      x] - (q^2/\[Epsilon]s)*(-NA - NC300/E^((EgT + Ev[x])/(kb*T)) + 
        NV300*E^(Ev[x]/(kb*T))) == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[{Ev[x] == Ev0}, x == xp]}, Ev[x], {x, 0, xp}]

Plot[sol, {x, 0, xp}]
```

[image]

A few more comments: `NeumannValue[0, ...]` can be omitted. This is the implicit default. Both `DirichletCondition` and `NeumannValues` are boundary conditions and apply only on the boundary. Specifying a predicate like `x>=1.5 xp` is not useful unless you made special modifications to the mesh (which you have not done)